# is it possible to edit MainPage.xaml from C# code?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

In my case in need change this

```
<DrawinSurfaceBackgroundGridgx:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground"Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded">
</DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid>
```

to this

```
<Grid>
<phone:WebBrowser Name="MiniBrowser" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGridx:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground"Loaded=
    "DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded">
    </DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid>
</Grid>
```

When unity3d build default project there is a default MainPage. I need too add a webbrowser component in this mainpage from my unity3d plugin. And then i need to call browser navigate and subscribe to some browser events like loadCompleted Is it possible? Plese give me an example

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. Can you give any more detail about what you want to do?

Comment: Why don't you just do this in xaml as opposed to runtime? We have documents that describe how to raise events from Unity and get them in the xaml/c# project side: unity3d.com/pages/windows/porting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get add/remove items programatically. If you can access the MainPage class you can get to it's content, which is the grid, and to its children which is an UIElementCollection which implements IList.

IList has an insert method which allows you to insert an element at a specified index, in your case 0, here a full example:

```
MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
var miniBrowser = new WebBrowser
{
    Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;      
};
mainPage.Content.Children.Insert(0, miniBrowser);
```

I didn't add a name to the WebBrowser class since because it is being added programatically it really makes no difference (the Name property is used at design time (xaml is parsed at design time and at runtime[in the InitializeComponent method]) to generate a property in a partial class (MainPage.i.g.cs/MainPage.g.cs)).

The way you get hold of MainPage is usually from Application.Current.Content (Application.Current will contain a Frame whose Content is MainPage).